# ERC721 Tx judgement in Etherscan

Tags: ethereum, etherscan

In Etherscan, the ERC721 Token Tx section on the address screen of each account is displayed separately, and I wonder how they judge the ERC721 Token Tx. If anyone knows anything about this, I'm eagerly waiting for any answers. below the etherscan image what i said.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see all the erc721 txns logs have the erc721 transfer event, so I think it's using the event to judge whether it's ERC721 Token Tx or not